# Convert string to boolean or integer inside bool_and in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query to retrieve all the records having `state = 'error'` until the state is something different [based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900963/select-until-row-matches-in-postgresql).

The current query looks like this

```
SELECT * from (select id, subscription_id, state, created_at,
   bool_and(state='error') OVER (order by created_at, id) AS ok 
   FROM messages ORDER by created_at) m2 
   WHERE subscription_id = 1;
```

However as you can see below all states are being treated as false, ignoring the `bool_and(state='error')` condition.

```
   id    | subscription_id | state |         created_at         | ok 
---------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------+----
   69480 |               1 | error | 2015-06-30 15:20:03.041045 | f
   69482 |               1 | error | 2015-06-30 15:20:04.582907 | f
   69492 |               1 | sent  | 2015-06-30 22:50:04.50478  | f
   69494 |               1 | error | 2015-06-30 22:50:06.067279 | f
   69502 |               1 | error | 2015-07-01 22:50:02.356113 | f
```

I would expect all `ok` rows to return `t` when `state = 'error'` and `f` when state has something else.

I read that `bool_and` only takes booleans and integers, but I'm not sure about this given the result of the condition is supposed to be boolean?

Any idea why this is not working and how to make sure it work?

Comment: you dont partition aggregation for `bool_and` so it aggregates it over all rows - so you have one state=sent which means bool_and(state='error') is false overall - right?.. try adding `partition by state` to `over(`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: sure thing, no worries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't partition aggregation for `bool_and` so it aggregates it over all rows - so you have one `state=sent` which means `bool_and(state='error') is false` overall

try adding `partition by state` to `over(` part

**update**
 better changing

```
bool_and(state='error') OVER (order by created_at, id) AS ok
```

to

```
bool_and(state='error') OVER (partition by state) AS ok
```

Comment: However when adding at the end of the query `AND ok = true` it seems it is not stopping after finding the `state = sent` but rather just retrieving all the 4 `state = 'error'` records.

Comment: can you please update post with exact expected return, data sample and table structure? So I could debug the problem?..

Comment: I believe this is better formulated as a new question, please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44519961/select-until-row-matches-in-postgres

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT      id
                , subscription_id
                , state
                , created_at
                , bool_and(state = 'error')
                OVER (PARTITION BY state ORDER BY created_at, id) AS ok 
        FROM        messages
        ORDER BY    created_at
    ) AS m2
WHERE   subscription_id= 1;
```