# Select until row matches in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Given the following data structure:

```
 id | subscription_id | state |         created_at         | ok 
---------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------+----
  1 |               1 | error | 2015-06-30 15:20:03.041045 | f
  2 |               1 | error | 2015-06-30 15:20:04.582907 | f
  3 |               1 | sent  | 2015-06-30 22:50:04.50478  | f
  4 |               1 | error | 2015-06-30 22:50:06.067279 | f
  5 |               1 | error | 2015-07-01 22:50:02.356113 | f
```

I want to retrieve the last messages with `state='error'` until the `state` contains something else.

It should return this:

```
 id | subscription_id | state |         created_at         | ok 
---------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------+----
  4 |               1 | error | 2015-06-30 22:50:06.067279 | f
  5 |               1 | error | 2015-07-01 22:50:02.356113 | f
```

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900963/select-until-row-matches-in-postgresql) and [later this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44518900/convert-string-to-boolean-or-integer-inside-bool-and-in-postgres/44519197?noredirect=1#comment76030974_44519197), I ended up with this query below:

```
SELECT * from (select id, subscription_id, state, created_at,
   bool_and(state='error') 
   OVER (PARTITION BY state order by created_at, id) AS ok 
   FROM messages ORDER by created_at) m2 
   WHERE subscription_id = 1;
```

However, given that I added `PARTITION BY state` the query is simply ignoring all `state` which does not contain `error` and showing this instead:

```
 id | subscription_id | state |         created_at         | ok 
---------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------+----
  1 |               1 | error | 2015-06-30 15:20:03.041045 | f
  2 |               1 | error | 2015-06-30 15:20:04.582907 | f
  4 |               1 | error | 2015-06-30 22:50:06.067279 | f
  5 |               1 | error | 2015-07-01 22:50:02.356113 | f
```

How should the query be made in order to 'stop' after finding a different state and matching following the example described on the top only the ids 4 and 5?

Comment: If you have 1 row also (with `id = 6` and `state=sent`), then what is desirable result? same as in question ?

Comment: Good question. It should not return any rows at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you need this:

```
select * from messages 
where
id > (select coalesce(max(id), 0) from messages  where state <> 'error')
and
subscription_id = 1
```

Assuming that `id` is unique (PK ?) column and higher id means latest record.

**EDIT**

Thats correct, as @Marth mentioned, probably you need add `... AND subscription_id = 1` in subquery

Comment: Interesting approach, however it is returning `(0 rows)`.

Comment: According to your sample data in question, this should return 2 last records (with id 4 and 5)

Comment: @OtoShavadze: Probably missing a `AND subscription_id = 1` in the subquery (for instance if subscription 2 has `id = 6 AND state = 'success'`).

Comment: @OtoShavadze What is all results are `state = 'error'` for a particular `subscription_id`? The current query returns 0 and the appropiate behaviour would be to return all of them.

Comment: @Martin - Good catch, in that case `coalesce()` would help, please check edited answer

Answer (score 2):

No need to `PARTITION BY state`, you want to `SELECT` rows where all rows afterward (in the `created_at ASC` order) are `error`, ie `bool_and(state = 'error')` is `true`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *,
         bool_and(state = 'error') OVER (ORDER BY created_at DESC, id) AS only_errors_afterward
  FROM sub
) s
WHERE only_errors_afterward
;
┌────┬─────────────────┬───────┬───────────────────────────────┬────┬───────────────────────┐
│ id │ subscription_id │ state │          created_at           │ ok │ only_errors_afterward │
├────┼─────────────────┼───────┼───────────────────────────────┼────┼───────────────────────┤
│  5 │               1 │ error │ 2015-07-01 22:50:02.356113+02 │ f  │ t                     │
│  4 │               1 │ error │ 2015-06-30 22:50:06.067279+02 │ f  │ t                     │
└────┴─────────────────┴───────┴───────────────────────────────┴────┴───────────────────────┘
(2 rows)
```

---

Edit: Depending on the expected result you might need a `PARTITION BY subscription_id` in the window function.